# Cancel async fetch request in React Native using Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, expo

I have a React Native app that has been built using Expo (v35.0.0). I have a simple async function (`loadData()`) that runs a fetch (via `fetchData()`) request to an API that the response is then passed into my redux store:

```
const loadData = async (id, token) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    await dispatch(fetchData(id, token));
  } catch (error) {
    setHasError(true);
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
  loadData(user.client.id, user.token);
}, [user.client.id]);
```

However, when the user logs out we are presented with the warning: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component", which I understand is because the async request has been cancelled.

I have attempted to implement the `AbortController` approach (as outlined in this article: https://dev.to/iquirino/react-hook-clean-up-useeffect-24e7), however then we are presented with an error stating `AbortConroller` is unknown.

I thought that support for `AbortConroller` would be within Expo now as it was added to React Native back in July last year as part of the v0.60 release.

So, **is it possible to implement `AbortController` within Expo** to cancel the async request? If not, **how should I go about cancelling the request** to avoid the warning (& memory leak)?

Comment: In your `useEffect` hook, you can return a cleanup function, with this you can set a flag, and then if it's set abort instead of calling setState..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `dispatch` is async, it's possible for it to finish after your component is unmounted.

Inside `useEffect` you can return a function that you call to cleanup.  Here you can set a flag to indicate the component is no longer mounted, and if this flag indicates it's no longer mounted, you can tell it not to update state.

eg.

```
let mounted = true;

const loadData = async (id, token) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    await dispatch(fetchData(id, token));
  } catch (error) {
    if (mounted) setHasError(true);
  }
  if (mounted) setIsLoading(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
  loadData(user.client.id, user.token);
  return () => mounted = false;
}, [user.client.id]);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Keith. Would still be interested to know why `AbortController` isn't operational within Expo but this solves my question.